# How does one refer to "raisins" in French?

Tags: anglicismes, faux-amis

The English word "grape" is apparently also from French, although *une grappe* refers to a whole bunch of grapes, not just one grape.

In English the word "raisin" refers to a dried grape, whereas in French, *un raisin* might be assumed to be a plump juicy fresh grape.

I am a little unsure of the commonly suggested terminology *un raisin sec,* i.e., "dry grape" as if there are one or two shriveled up on the vine, or else one is referring to something entirely different, a type of "dry wine" (*vin sec*) for instance.

Not to mention "vine" in English refers to the stem or the branch of the grape plant, not *le vin* or "the wine."

Apparently grapes are typically made into wine in France, not "dried" commercially as raisins sold in U.S. supermarkets. And I have not really heard or seen the term *raisins séchés* in use although this would seem more accurate and descriptive of the product I am referring to, *raisins qui ont été séchés*.

Or what is best way to avoid confusion where it appears that a certain degree of intemperance has affected the use of language over time?

Comment: In *Jean de Florette*, Ugolin tells Jean that due to the drought, all the farmer's *raisins* are « comme ceux qu'on met dans la brioche » !

Comment: So far the weather has not been dry enough  in France to produce large quantities of *raisins secs* (which would be "dri**ed** grapes" in English, and not "dry grapes"). Wikipedia has good articles on the subject. You might want to review your question (not very clear at this point) after you understand more of the process used to dry the grapes to make raisin, which are definitely not dried on the vine. As far as I know the only kind of dried fruit France produces is *pruneau" and they are not dried in the sun (of which there would not be enough) but in industrial conveniences.

Comment: You might also compare the English  "prune" and "plum" with French *prune* and *pruneau.*

Comment: No relation to your question, but your quotes look wrong.《》are (according to wikipedia) Chinese quotes. The French ones are «».

Comment: "un raisin" in French sounds unusual, unless it refers to the grape variety maybe? I have usually seen either "un grain" or "une grappe" to refer to either.

Comment: regarding your vine vs wine comment - I believe that French has that too, we say "vigne" (latin vitis) for the vine plant, whereas it is "vin" (latin vinum) for the wine. they both come from similar but different Latin roots (vitis / vinum) -- I would not be surprised if the Latin words were related, though I am not aware of them being so

Comment: @FlorianCastellane *Vigne* comes from the Latin *[vinea](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vinea)*, definitely related to *vinum*. On the other hand *vitis* gave the French *viticulture* which despite the similarity isn't reported to be etymologically related.

Answer (score 8):

*How does one refer to "raisins" in French?*

We call them ***[raisins secs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisin_sec)***.

The French ***grappe*** doesn't mean "bunch of grapes" but just "cluster" so ***une grappe de raisin*** translates to "**a cluster of grapes**".

Unlike other Romance languages that kept the Latin ***uva*** to name the fruit, French took the Latin ***racimus/recimus*** (cluster of grapes) to do it.

***Raisin*** is often uncountable: *j'ai acheté **du** raisin* is more usual than *j'ai acheté **des** raisins*.

[image]

That's also the reason why *raisin* is often singular in *une grappe de raisin* (unlike the English "of grapes".) To name a single grape, we usually say *un **grain de raisin*** instead of *un raisin*.

***Grappe*** has a Germanic origin from a word meaning "hook", cognates with "grasp". It still exists with this old meaning in the colloquial idiom ***[lâche-moi la grappe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A2cher_la_grappe)*** (literally: "drop the hook from me", i.e. give me a break, leave me alone). See also *un **[grappin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grappin)***.

Note that we do not call a "**cluster** of bananas" a ***grappe** de bananes* but a ***régime** de bananes*. Interestingly, this ***[régime](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9gime)***, like ***raisins***, comes from the Vulgar Latin ***racimus*** but this time via the Spanish ***racimo*** meaning "cluster".

Comment: Re "*Raisin is often uncountable: j'ai acheté du raisin is more usual than j'ai acheté des raisins.*", This might be regional? Always countable here. ("J'ai acheté/mangé/etc des raisins").

Comment: @ikegami Maybe, we do not know where is "here" but I would be surprised the uncountable usage would be unknown by native French. Anyway, I'm talking about common usage in France.

Comment: Le français est me langue maternelle. Je suis Canadien (NB, pas QC). Your graph shows "des raisins" is consistently used at least one times in 3 between "des raisins" and "du raisin", so it does appear quite popular.

Comment: @ikegami Oui, je n'ai pas écrit que raisin était toujours indénombrable, seulement qu'il était plus souvent employé comme ça. On dit aussi bien sûr aussi *J'ai acheté **des raisins*** par chez nous mais moins que *j'ai acheté **du raisin*** alors que par exemple on dira beaucoup plus *J'ai acheté **des pommes*** que *j'ai acheté **de la pomme***.

Comment: So 'Grappe' is a faux amis, and could refer to bananas just as well?

Comment: @Michael Both *grappe* and *raisins* are faux-amis indeed. For bananas, there is a specific word, *un régime de bananes* (where *régime* is a faux-ami too [answer updated], not to mention *régime* might also mean "diet"). The words *grappe* is very often followed by *de raisin(s)* but we can say *une grappe de groseilles, de lilas, de fruits, de fleurs, etc.* and even sometimes *une grappe d'ordinateurs* (a computer cluster).

Answer (score 5):

The adjective *sec* can have several meanings.

If we look at the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sec) we have the following definition:

> Qui a subi un traitement destiné à la déshydratation plus ou moins complètement, généralement pour assurer sa conservation<sup>1</sup>.

which is the meaning used in *raisins secs*, it qualifies a dehydrated substance.

When used for wine the word *sec* does not refer to a harder or softer substance induced by a greater or lesser quantity of humidity but to the taste which can vary according to the quantity of sugar  contained in the wine. *Un vin sec* (less sugar) is opposed to *vin doux* (more sugar).
Again if we look at the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sec):

> 5. [Qualifie un vin] Peu liquoreux, à saveur plus ou moins acide<sup>2</sup>.

In *raisins secs* (as in *abricots secs*) *sec* refers to the end product. For other fruit we would say *figues séchées*, *bananes séchées*, etc... referring to the process and not to the end product.
[*Fruits secs*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_sec) is a generic term that is only used for nuts, and where the word *sec* qualifies a substance that has not been dehydrated, but that is dry by nature.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Which has undergone a treatment intended to dehydrate it more or less completely, generally to ensure its preservation.

<sup>2</sup> [Qualifies a wine] Not very sweet, with a more or less acidic taste.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[*Raisins secs*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisin_sec) (and *fruits séchés* in general) are a common feature in France, and can be bought in any supermarket or at a *maraichers* (grocery store). However, it is necessary to point out that the grapes used to make dry grapes are usually not the same as those used for making wine.

*La grappe* refers to a part of a plant, whereas *raisin/raisins* refers to the fruits that people eat. This is somewhat similar to how in English one uses different terms to refer to an animal and its meat: pig/pork, cow/beef, etc.

English has borrowed quite a lot of words from French, and unsurprizingly some of them have changed their meaning and became *translator's false friends*, like *grape* and *grappe* (one could also mention [*grappa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grappa) - strong alcoholic beverage produced in Italy... obviously from grapes.) However, in the case of *wine/vine* we likely have correspondence *wine-vin* and *vine-vigne*.

**Remark:**
@None has brought my attention to the difference between [*fruits séchés*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_s%C3%A9ch%C3%A9) and *fruits secs*. The former are *raisins secs*, *abricots secs*, *figues séchées*, etc. On the other hand, [*fruits sec*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_sec) are nuts and similar.

Comment: As a French native and cook addict, I would never qualify *raisins secs* as [*fruits secs*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_sec).

Comment: @None Thanks for pointing it out that *fruits secs* refers to something different. What would be a generic term for *raisin sec*, *pruneau sec*, *abricot sec*, etc.?

Comment: Usually *pruneau* (only used for the dried fruit, if Fresh it is *prune*, so no *sec* with it), *abricots secs* and *raisins secs*. To refer to *figues séchées*,  *bananes séchées*, *pruneaux* and other dried fruit I'd say [*fruits séchés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_s%C3%A9ch%C3%A9)*.  If I walk into a store and want to know where they keep the *raisins secs* and *figues séchées* I'd say "*où sont les fruits séchés*", but  in most stores *fruits secs* and *fruits séchés* are kept on the same shelves.

Comment: @None Thanks, I updated my answer. I hope you do not mind using your knowledge (I mentioned you).

Comment: Absolutely no problem! The point is to give correct info, not to score. Also: [*maraichers*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara%C3%AEchage) grows vegetables, and might sell them on the farm or the local market, but they are primarily  growers. I think the word you wanted to use is [épicier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara%C3%AEchage).